# How to subcript a text

Tags: r

I need to subcript the letter T (with an e) in the following text:

"In/Out RZ Te = 400s"

In Latex I would do $T_{e}$. I need the same but in R.

I need to add the value to a cell in a dataframe

Comment: is this in a plot / document / or? but likely you want to red `?plotmath` (hint: `~T[e]`)

Comment: I need to add the value to a cell in a dataframe.

Comment: okay. To what aim please? This is fairly non-standard as outputs in the terminal are generally plain text. You can use subscripts in tables outputs to html, tex, and figures etc which would be a more standard way to present results. But its not impossible, you could use unicode (`data.frame(x="T\U2091")`) but I'd think this is not very flexible / going to cause problems down the line

Comment: afterwards these cells will be the text in the strips of a gglplot facet_grid

Comment: btw, when I do print(x="T\U2091") It does not work. For instance, x="T\U2122" works.

Comment: ah okay. So if you are wanting to use in plots a more standard way is to use `expression`'s like in the first comment. This can have slightly nicer formatting and be more flexible. There are many examples in SO of using subscripts  in ggplot facet labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316214/how-to-apply-subscript-in-the-facet-grid-function-of-ggplot may be useful

Comment: ... e.g. `d = data.frame(x=1, y=1, 
               z="'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '400s'", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ; 
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + facet_wrap(~z, labeller=label_parsed)`

Comment: but I'm using facet_grid, not facet_wrap

Comment: did you try the example, changing facet_wrap to facet_grid (and tweaking the facet function)

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried but you can very nicely see the subscript with facet_wrap and not with facet_grid.

Comment: `ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + facet_grid(~z, labeller=label_parsed)` and `ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + facet_grid(.~z, labeller=label_parsed)` produce similar results for me.

Comment: If you continue to have difficulties I recommend you ask a new question giving a reproducible example

Comment: how would you do it with an extra column? Let's say "'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '400s'" and "'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '600s'". Maybe that is closer to my case.

Comment: You just need to create an expression for each facet. I tend to dind it easier to create a vector of facet labels outside of the data data.frame and pass this to the ggplot functions. An example, `d = data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2, z=1:2); lbs = c('1'="'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '400s'", '2'="'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '600s'") ; ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +  facet_grid(.~z, labeller=as_labeller(lbs, label_parsed))` (of course if your facet variable is coded as `400, 600` etc you could use `bquote` to automate constructing the expressions)

Comment: Thank you verye much but still not working, the only thing different now between your plot and mine is that I also have variables on the right side of the plot, meaning facet_grid(something~z).

Comment: It worked, thanks. Would you also know how to add a line break after "RZ"? The text is too long for a single line.

Comment: one way is to use `atop` e.g. `lbs = c('1'="atop('In/Out RZ',T[e]== '400s')", 
        '2'="'In/Out RZ'*~T[e]== '600s'")`.  See`?plotmath` for details.